# Jquery Click Event on Parent Class "highlight"

Tags: jquery, click

Trying to add a click event on parent of "highlight." Adding and removing classes correctly but the click event is stopping after the addClass of close.

```
$(function () {
    $(".open").click(function () {
        $('#rslide').animate({
            right: '-375px'
        }, 400);
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('close');
    });
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $('#rslide').animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, 400);
        $(this).removeClass('close');
        $(this).addClass('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this or post your HTML?

Comment: try `$(document).on("click",'.open',function() {...});`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm56F/

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only bind the events to elements that *currently* match the selector when the code runs.

You can use the ["on" event binding](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events to elements that will match the selector *at the time*.

```
$("body").on("click", ".open", function(event) {
    $self = $(this);
    $('#rslide').animate({
        right: '-375px'
    }, 400);
    $self.removeClass('open');
    $self.addClass('close');
});

$("body").on("click", ".close", function(event) {
    $self = $(this);
    $('#rslide').animate({
        right: '0px'
    }, 400);
    $self.removeClass('close');
    $self.addClass('open');
});
```

I have placed `$(this)` into a variable to avoid repeatedly wrapping `this` in a jQuery object, but you could chain instead: `$(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');`

Comment: it will work fine but in optimisation term .on is certainly unnecessery here

Answer (score 0):

as you use the two class on the **same elements**, your code is redondant and not need "live" event

as we not use "live" event, jquery will never update elements targeted by the selector, so if in future they not match original selector the click event will continue to work on them

```
$(".open").click(function(){
    alert("click!");
}).removeClass("open");
```

for your specific case, first you need a selector for all your elements, if at start all of them are opened, use $(".open") if it's a mixin, use $(".open, .close"), and there certainly must be a better selector like $("#parent > article") just check your html for that

here we not get your html, so i assume it's a mixin, $(".open, .close")

we need to check the current class and done different action, jquery get function to check a class

```
$(this).hasClass("open");
```

or

```
$(this).is(".open");
```

=>

```
$(".open, .close").click(function(){
    var isOpen = $(this).hasClass("open");

    if(isOpen) alert("opened!"); else alert("closed!");
});
```

with your current code :

```
$(".open, .close").click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var isOpen = $t.hasClass("open");

    if(isOpen){
        $('#rslide').animate({right:-375},400);
        $t.removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    } else {
        $('#rslide').animate({right:0},400);
        $t.removeClass('close').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

but it still some redondant code, let simplify this more :

```
$(".open, .close").click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var isOpen = $t.hasClass("open");
    $('#rslide').animate({right:(-375*isOpen)},400);
    $t.toggleClass('open').toggleClass('close');
});
```

toggleClass is certainly not great, it must check the class before, try remove it

```
$(".open, .close").click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var isOpen = $t.hasClass("open") * 1;
    var cls = ["open","close"];
    $('#rslide').animate({right:(-375*isOpen)},400);
    $t.removeClass(cls[!isOpen]).addClass(cls[isOpen]);
});
```